# Android : How to make transparent dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialog, android-transitions

I need some thing like this:

> [image]

To make a transparent dialog box such that background can be seen from it. Can any one help ?

Comment: you can see my answer below,

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Dialog mDialog = new Dialog(mContext, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Activity.this);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.xml);
                    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));]

Button cancel = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.cancel);
                    // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
                    ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v)
                        {
                        // stuff
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Thank you.It's working fine.But i need one more functionality.I have two buttons in the layout file.How to add click listeners to those buttons...

Comment: How to add listeners to those buttons ??